# SSRS expression to check if a string is present in a string array

Tags: reporting-services, filter, report

I am applying a filter to a Series Group in Report.
I want to filter out data by country name.
For ex. I would like to filter out Nepal, Japan & China.
Right now my filter expression is to add 3 filters, one for each country. Is there a better way to do it, may be in a single filter?
Ideally I am imagining it to be like
[CountryName] Not In ["Japan","China","Nepal"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a bit of custom code to detect the country instead, and filter on that.

```
Public Function IsProhibitedCountry(ByVal name As String) As Boolean
Select Case name.ToLower()
Case "japan","china","nepal"
   Return False
Case Else
   Return True
End Select
End Function
```

The filter:

```
[=Code.IsProhibitedCountry(Fields!CountryName.Value)]  [=]  [=True]
```